# Using Total inside the RecurrenceTable

Tags: recursion, difference-equations

I would like to perform an operation over [`IntegerDigits`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/IntegerDigits.html) recurrently.

The operation is the sum of cubes of the digits, for example:

$12 \rightarrow (1^3 + 2^3) = 9$.

Outside of the [`RecurrenceTable`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RecurrenceTable.html) all looks fine:

```
f[k_] := Total[IntegerDigits[k]^3]
f[12]
(* out: 9 *)
```

But inserted inside the `RecurrenceTable`, the output is not what I expect:

```
RecurrenceTable[{a[n+1] == Total[IntegerDigits[a[n]]^3], a[1] == 12}, a, {n, 1, 3}] 
(* out: {12,{4,5},{{7},{8}}} *)
```

**Why does it behave this way and what is the right way to do such task?**

Comment: Welcome! To make the most of Mma.SE start by **taking the [tour] now**. It will **help us to help you** if you write an [excellent question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). [Edit](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/editing-help) if improvable, show due diligence, give brief context, include **minimal working example** of code and data in **[formatted form](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/editing-help)**. As you receive **give back**, vote and answer questions, keep the site useful, be kind, correct mistakes and share what you have learned.

Comment: What's the expected output for `n=3`? `a[1]=12`, then `a[2]=f[a[1]]=f[12]=9`, and then `a[3]=f[a[2]]=f[9]=9^3=729`? And next would be `a[4]=f[a[3]]=f[729]=1080`? Then the straightforward way would be `NestList[f, 12, 3]` yielding `{12, 9, 729, 1080}`

Comment: Inspired by this thread, I [posted a question about it](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2802364/properties-of-the-recurrent-sum-of-cubes-of-the-digits-of-integers) on math.SE

Comment: @corey979, The actual origin of the task is [from here](https://brilliant.org/weekly-problems/2018-05-28/intermediate/?p=5)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First, as [I noted in the comment](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/174288/using-total-inside-the-recurrencetable#comment457543_174288), a much simpler approach is to use `NestList`:

```
NestList[f, 12, 3]
```

> {12, 9, 729, 1080}

---

Let's explain what happens when `RecurrenceTable` is employed.

First, let's see how the code is run:

```
RecurrenceTable[{a[n + 1] == Total[IntegerDigits[a[n]]^3], 
   a[1] == 12}, a, {n, 1, 3}] // Trace
```

[image]

This yields a suspicious term `a[1+n] == 3 + IntegerDigits[a[n]]`. So, let's see a `FullForm`:

```
Total[IntegerDigits[a[n]]^3] // FullForm
```

> 3 + IntegerDigits[a[n]]

Something's wrong with `Total`! Or is it? From the docs: "`Total[list]` is equivalent to `Apply[Plus, list]`". So, because the `FullForm` of `IntegerDigits[a]^3` is `Power[IntegerDigits[a], 3]`, one gets from `Apply[Plus, Power[IntegerDigits[a], 3]` the incorrect expression `3 + IntegerDigits[a]`. So one cannot use `Total` like this.

So maybe `Sum` will be a solution?

```
Sum[(IntegerDigits[a[n]]^3)[[i]], {i, 1, Length@(IntegerDigits[a[n]]^3)}]
```

> 3 + IntegerDigits[a[n]]

Not good; it gives the same result as `Total`. Some weird ideas like `#^3 & /@ IntegerDigits[a[n]]` are also no good.

Let's define then

```
g[k_Integer] := Block[{seq}, seq = IntegerDigits[k]; 
  Sum[seq[[i]]^3, {i, 1, Length@seq}]]
```

Then, `g[a[n]]` gives `g[a[n]]` - this is **good**, because if we skip the `Integer` part from the definition, we'll get `a[n]^3` instead, leading to new problems (to see what's going on under the hood in such a case, run `RecurrenceTable[{a[n + 1] == g[a[n]], a[1] == 12}, a, {n, 1, 2}] // Trace`).

So, eventually, with the above (proper) definition of `g` one gets:

```
RecurrenceTable[{a[n + 1] == g[a[n]], a[1] == 12}, a, {n, 1, 4}]
```

> {12, 9, 729, 1080}

But still... If there's such a difference between defining `g[k_]` and `g[k_Integer]`, then maybe let's come back to the very beginning and define `f` as

```
Clear[f]
f[k_Integer] := Total[IntegerDigits[k]^3]
```

Then

```
RecurrenceTable[{a[n + 1] == f[a[n]], a[1] == 12}, a, {n, 1, 4}]
```

> {12, 9, 729, 1080}

yields the correct answer!

So the whole convoluted line of reasoning lead to simply adding `Integer` to the initial definition. Comparing the `FullForm`s of the two versions, one sees that in the `Integer` case the function is **not evaluated at all** unless it gets an argument with the specified `Head` - in this case, `Integer`, i.e. a definite number on which all the arithmetics can be performed without the unexpected behaviour of `Total`. So, in the end, this makes perfect sense.

---

### Mathematical questions that arise

What happens with the sequence for large `n`? Let's simultaneously investigate this with the dependence on the initial condition `a[1]==a1`:

```
ListPlot[RecurrenceTable[{a[n + 1] == f[a[n]], a[1] == #}, 
     a, {n, 1, 100}], PlotLabel -> #, PlotRange -> All, 
    Frame -> True] & /@ Range[100] // FlipView
```

Checking the above plots, one'll notice that the sequences converge to either 1, 2, or 3 interchanging values, e.g.

[image]

Is it universal? Let's compute the sequences (of length 100) for $a_1\in [1,10^4]$, take the last 20 iterations, `DeleteDuplicates` and calculate the `Length`:

```
(per = Length /@ 
    DeleteDuplicates /@ (RecurrenceTable[{a[n + 1] == f[a[n]], 
          a[1] == #}, a, {n, 80, 100}] & /@ Range[10000])) // 
 ListPlot[#, Frame -> True, PlotRange -> All] &
```

[image]

Indeed, only three values occur, with the frequencies

```
Tally[per]
```

> {{1, 8543}, {3, 956}, {2, 501}}

I haven't noticed any obvious pattern in the `a1`s that lead to different multiplicities of the limitting sequence. Questions that arise:

1. Are the numbers $1,2,3$ the only multiplicities possible for all $a_1\in\mathbb{N}$?
2. What governs the value of the multiplicity in dependence on $a_1$?
3. How universal this behaviour is when sums of squares, quartics, etc. are considered?
4. Do other types of functions of the `IntegerDigits` have such interesting/universal properties?
5. What are other interesting questions to ask about?

Comment: We seem to have arrived at very similar conclusions :-)

Comment: @MarcoB Hm, you posted your answer while I was writting up my and didn't see it before I posted; sorry. However, mine is a bit more in-depth about how to arrive to such conclusions, and I provide a different workaround than you, so let me leave my answer as it is.

Comment: Oh yes, that's fine! I didn't mean to suggest that you had to change anything. In fact, I upvoted your answer.

Comment: @MarcoB Same; inactivating `Total` is a neat trick. Although, I've just found the _ultimate_ solution - see my edit :)

Comment: @corey979, Thank you  for such a detailed deep dive. That gives me insights on how to investigate things by myself. One question tho, what was your intuition behind trying to fix the type in the function definition `f[k_Integer]` ? I do not see how your previous steps leads to this idea.

Comment: @Kiryaka An attempt to prevent the function from evaluating before it gets the _right_ argument to evaluate on.

Answer (score 7):

The problem is that in your equation within `RecurrenceTable` the expression

```
Total[IntegerDigits[a[n]]^3]
```

"prematurely" evaluates to :

```
3 + IntegerDigits[a[n]]
```

In a simpler case, you can see this more clearly:

```
Clear[x]
Total[x^3] (* which is the same as Total[Power[x, 3]] *)
(*Out:  x + 3*)
```

Indeed, this may be surprising, but it is behavior described in the documentation. In fact,

> `Total[list]` is equivalent to `Apply[Plus, list]`
>
> `Total[f[e1, e2, ...]]` gives the sum of the $e_i$ for any head $f$.

---

You can define the transformation as a separate function, or you can brute-force your way around it by temporarily inactivating `Total`, then reactivating it at the end of the calculation:

```
RecurrenceTable[
  {a[n + 1] == Inactive[Total][IntegerDigits[a[n]]^3], a[1] == 12}, a, {n, 1, 9}
] // Activate

(* Out: {12, 9, 729, 1080, 513, 153, 153, 153, 153} *)
```

Answer (score 5):

An alternative solution is [`NestList`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NestList.html)

```
ClearAll[f];
f[k_Integer] := Total[IntegerDigits[k]^3]
NestList[f, 12, 7]
```

> ```
> {12, 9, 729, 1080, 513, 153, 153, 153}
> ```

or

```
ClearAll[f];
f[k_Integer] := Sum[i^3, {i, IntegerDigits[k]}]
```

---

Other answers already gave a better explanation on the behaviour of you observed in `RecurrenceTable` been a consequence of the definition of `Total` as `Apply[Plus,list]`, implying that the `Head` of the expression is replaced by `Plus`. As noted in the comments I mistakenly used `Integers` instead of `Integer` in my attempts of solution.

Comment: Why did you use type case in your functions? I'm asking because the way you define the function - it will also works perfectly fine inside the RecurrenceTable (see corey979 investigation). So what was you intuition behind restricting the type? Is it just that you always try to be as type strict as possible for the task, or is it something about this exactly this task that require it?

Comment: @Kiryaka Mostly as a habit, it's good practice to constrain the definition to the argument you are expecting to have.  In this case I also though `RecurrenceTable ` was trying to be clever and do some analytical test on the function.  As presumably `IntegerDigits` would not act as a well behaved algebraic definition, I thought was best to avoide any other evaluation other than with an `Integer`.